# Get package name of default image openner

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-package-managers

I have a problem. When running my tests on different phones, when trying to open gallery, it is not working.

Now, what I want to do is to get package name for the default gallery opener app, so I can use it in my code. How can I do this programmatically?

Here is how am I using when running tests on Nexus 5.

```
Resources resources = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getResources();
        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" +
                resources.getResourcePackageName(R.drawable.ic_launcher) + '/' +
                resources.getResourceTypeName(R.drawable.ic_launcher) + '/' +
                resources.getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        Intent resultData = new Intent();
        resultData.setData(imageUri);
        Instrumentation.ActivityResult result = new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultData);
        intending(toPackage("com.google.android.apps.photos")).respondWith(result);
        //Click the select button
        onView(withId(R.id.register_image)).perform(click());
        threadSleep(MILISECONDS_TIMEOUT);
        onView(withText("From Gallery")).perform(click());
        threadSleep(MILISECONDS_TIMEOUT);
        Spoon.screenshot(getActivityInstance(), "picture_selected");
```

Basically, all i need to do is to get package name of the application for images.

Comment: The readability of your code snippet is horrible. Hopefully, your coding skills have improved enough since the past 5 years to avoid such problems. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you will want to do something like this:

Create utils class and add the following method:

```
 public static String getPackageForGalery() {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            mainIntent.setType("image/*");
            List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);
            int size = pkgAppsList.size();
            for (ResolveInfo infos : pkgAppsList) {
                return infos.activityInfo.processName;

            }
            return null;
        }
```

Now, in your code, do this:

```
Resources resources = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getResources();
        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" +
                resources.getResourcePackageName(R.drawable.ic_launcher) + '/' +
                resources.getResourceTypeName(R.drawable.ic_launcher) + '/' +
                resources.getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        Intent resultData = new Intent();
        resultData.setData(imageUri);
        Instrumentation.ActivityResult result = new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultData);
        intending(toPackage(YourUtilsClass.getPackageForGalery())).respondWith(result);
        //Click the select button
        onView(withId(R.id.register_image)).perform(click());
        threadSleep(MILISECONDS_TIMEOUT);
        onView(withText("From Gallery")).perform(click());
        threadSleep(MILISECONDS_TIMEOUT);
        Spoon.screenshot(getActivityInstance(), "picture_selected");
```

Answer (score 1):

[PackageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) is your friend here. Specifically to get a listing of all applications listening for an intent of your type you can use
[queryIntentActivities(Intent intent, int flags)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities(android.content.Intent,%20int)). This returns a list of matching activities for your intent ordered from most preferred. If there's not matching a resolver, the list will be empty, which may mean that your intent isn't properly formed.